# How to access a virtual machine behind a NAT from a public network

Tags: virtual-machine, nagios

I have a 1&1 hosting dedicated server (Linux Centos 5.x with Plesk) (`IP 74.208.98.x`) and I configured a NagiosXI virtual machine to run in NAT mode under VMware player 4.0. because I was unable to use bridge mode (where the 1&1's security system sees MAC spoofing from virtual machine and terminates my server/send it offline). The only possibility I can use is the NAT mode.

I want to know how I can communicate with the nagiosXI VM from the internet. It would be better if I were able to map the NagiosXI internal IP into one of my subdomains.  I do have a fixed static IP that I am thinking of using if possible so that the NagiosXI VM wont rely on DHCP.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by NAT mode?  The 74.208.246.x address is a public address, and you are NATting this to a private address your VM has?  What is doing the NATting?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the NAT configuration? If so, you can set up the VM's (internal) mac as the DMZ (so all of its ports are forwarded) or selectively forward ports for the protocols that you use.

Comment: I can only access NAT configuration in /etc/vmware/vmnet8/nat/nat.conf  .  I have disable the firewall in my server and i use plesk SMB firewall.  can i assign a public static IP in Virtual machine behind NAT? because that doesnt seems to work. configuring nagiosxi to use DHCP and i can able to ping from my host.. but assigning static IP, i wont able to ping.